# user defined array function, I do not see the mistake

Tags: arrays, c, user-defined-functions, swap

**The issue has been solved thanks to Eugene, however, I am still curious about what I did wrong with the user-defined function**I am a beginner and I do not see my mistake in this code, I am trying to print the array elements then swap the first and last element then print the values again, is it possible to swap without a user-defined function? if so how?
thank you in advance.
this is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int swap(int);
int main()
{
    int size;
    int a[5]={10,20,30,40,50};
    for(size=0;size<5;size++)
    {
        printf("%d",a[size]);
    }
    swap(a);
    size=0;
    for(size=0;size<5;size++)
    {
        printf("%d",a[size]);
    }
}
int swap(int)
{
    int temp=a[0];
    a[0]=a[4];
    a[4]=temp;
}
```

[image: codeblocks error codes]

Comment: Anything that can be done with a function can be done without. In your case it is simply copying the code from the `swap` function into `main` instead of the `swap` call

Comment: Those error messages tell you the problem and the line of code on which it occurs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you! that solved the problem, do you see what i did wrong when calling the user-defined function?

Comment: @paddy i know, however i do not know what the vocabulary and terms in the error message  mean, maybe i should google more, thank you .

Comment: Your `swap` is not really doing anything with a passed parameter. And it is also not defining the parameter list correctly. The parameters should come as pairs `type name`

Comment: Probably worth reading some introductory material on the C programming language.  There are multiple errors in your code.  Lots of excellent books exist.

Comment: @karamalqussiri there are some errors associated with function parameters and return types. You can refer to some resources on C programming to understand them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. would you mind further elaborating because i am not familiar with the terms and vocabulary you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message actually exactly tells you what is wrong:

`Parameter name missing.`
`a undefined...`
(Please do not post text error message as pictures. We cannot copy&paste it here form your picture.)

In function definition you must provide a name for each parameter. Otherwise you cannot use it inside that function:

```
int swap(int)
{
int temp=a[0];
a[0]=a[4];
a[4]=temp;
}
```

Here don't tell your compiler how that int parameter is called.
And on the other side you don't tell the compiler what you think, `a` should be. It is not visible in scope.

To fix that, change like this:

```
int swap(int a[])
{
int temp=a[0];
a[0]=a[4];
a[4]=temp;
}
```

That will solve the error messages you showed us.
But you should also get at least a warning about not retuning anything from a non-void function.
You defined return type as `int` but don't return any `int` value.
For a swap function there is normally no need to return anything.

Therefore use this:

```
void swap(int a[])
{
  int temp=a[0];
  a[0]=a[4];
  a[4]=temp;
}
```

Any decent beginners text book should clearly cover how function definitions have to look like.
You should not skip the first chapters when learning a new language.

Comment: Thank you! i appreciate your help and advice.